# selenium python clicking a href by text inside

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to switch countries programmatically in [this](http://www.asos.com/it/asos/asos-jeans-skinny-alla-caviglia-kaki/prd/6759361) site for some automation testing, the prices are different in each country so I am programming a little tool to help me decide where to buy from.

First, I get all the currencies into a list by doing this:

```
def get_all_countries():
    one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
    one.click()
    el = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "site-selector-list")))
    list_return = []
    a_tags = el.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for a in a_tags:
        list_return.append(a.text)
    return list_return
```

For example, it returns: `['United Kingdom', 'United States', 'France', 'Deutschland', 'España', 'Australia', 'Россия']` and then, I iterate through the list and each time calling this function:

```
def set_country(text):
    is_change_currency_displayed = driver1.find_element_by_id("siteSelectorList").is_displayed()
    if not is_change_currency_displayed:  # get_all_countries function leaves dropdown open. Check if it is open before clicking it.
        one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
        one.click()
    div = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "site-selector-list")))
    a_tags = div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for a in a_tags:
        try:
            if a.text == text:
                driver1.get(a.get_attribute("href"))
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            set_country(text)
```

When comparing a.text to text, I got a StaleElementReferenceException, I read online that it means the object is changed from when I saved it, and a simple solution is to call the function again. However, I don't like this solution and this code a lot, I think it is not effective and takes too much time, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
def main(url):
    driver1.get(url)
    to_return_string = ''
    one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
    one.click()
    el = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "site-selector-list")))
    a_tags = el.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for a in a_tags:
        atext = a.text
        ahref = a.get_attribute('href')
        try:
            is_change_currency_displayed = driver1.find_element_by_id("siteSelectorList").is_displayed()
            if not is_change_currency_displayed:  # get_all_countries function leaves dropdown open.
                one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
                one.click()
            driver1.get(ahref)
            current_price = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".current-price")))
            to_return_string += ("In " + atext + " : " + current_price.text + ' \n')
            print("In", atext, ":", current_price.text)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("In", atext, ":", "Timed out waiting for page to load")
            to_return_string += ("In " + atext + " : " + " Timed out waiting for page to load" + ' \n')
    return to_return_string


main('http://us.asos.com/asos//prd/7011279')
```

Comment: you are changing the webpage every time you are sending **driver.get** in **if a.text=text** condition. so, the original page is lost as DOM updated once **driver.get** is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem statement correctly, Adding `break` statement solves the problem:

```
def set_country(text):
    is_change_currency_displayed = driver1.find_element_by_id("siteSelectorList").is_displayed()
    if not is_change_currency_displayed:  # get_all_countries function leaves dropdown open. Check if it is open before clicking it.
        one = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "selected-currency")))
        one.click()
    div = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "site-selector-list")))
    a_tags = div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
    for a in a_tags:
        try:
            if a.text == text:
                driver1.get(a.get_attribute("href"))
                break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            set_country(text)
```

---

`DOM` is updated once `driver.get` is called. so, the references related to old page (i.e., a_tags) won't work.

Instead, `you should break the loop` and come out as soon as the given country page is retrieved using `driver.get` once the condition is satisfied. So, you set the country you want and no need to iterate over and over again to check if condition, which obviously results in `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

If your stale element is the `a` tag and not the `div`, you can iterate over the a tags length and get each element's text through the `div`:

```
for i in range(len(div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')):
    if div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[i].text == text:
        driver1.get(div.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[i].get_attribute("href"))
```

That way you can the most recent element from the DOM.

If your stale element is the `div` then you'll need to verify that the drop down isn't disappearing after your `one.click()` with hovering it or some other way.

Another approach would be to change your `a.text` to have a wait:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=1, ignored_exceptions=[StaleElementReferenceException])
a = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.YourBy)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that later when I will be near my computer, another question is, do you think getting the list of countries first is a good thing to do or to have one main function that iterates through the length of countries, each time clicks a different country and gets the price?

Comment: I tried option one, if the stale element is a, and it is still not working, so I guess it is the div, however, I haven't understood your solution.

Comment: Let's try to clarify the scenario: first of all you said its for automation testing, but from the description I see that you're trying to get info automatically from a website which is called "scraping" and this requires a different approach, am I right? If so, your better option will be to iterate in one main function and each time clicking the currency instead of getting a list first as it can cause stale elements. Another thing I would suggest is running in debug line by line with the browser open to see what happens and understand what exactly causes the exception.

Comment: Okay, so you are right, I thought anything you are trying to do with selenium is automation testing, I am trying to do scraping. anyway, I updated the code into one main function, and now the StaleElementReferenceException is in this line: atext = a.text. I also tried to change the code and every time get the a reference again, so I will not get this error, but I failed.